Excel Userform Dropdown List - Get data from all columns?
I created a userform with a combo dropdown list.  I got it to work in general.
My issue is, is that I can only bound it to one column from what I can tell.
In the screenshot for example has 3 columns.  Is there a way to pull all 3 columns?  perhaps enter them in a text box in the userform?
Thank you!

I've only tried to play with the BoundColumn properties, I don't know how else to achieve it what I am looking for.


Please share the relevant (best complete) code and a detailed description of how it fails.

We can access the ComboBox data using its List and use its ListIndex property to get the current row of data.
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    With ComboBox1
        Debug.Print .List(.ListIndex, 0), .List(.ListIndex, 1), .List(.ListIndex, 2)
    End With
End Sub

